# iOS - UIPanGestureRecognizer : drag during animation

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uipangesturerecognizer

i use UIPanGestureRecognizer to move an object along the path drawn by the user. But this object is animating and i need to interact with it during animation. Is it possible? I already try to use `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` but no results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5572717/1059705 & http://stackoverflow.com/q/8340329/1059705 this may help you

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But I would use `CABasicAnimation` for animating the object and not the `UIView animationWith...` and then add the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the object. So some example code:

```
// Configure the animation and add it to the layer.
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.fromValue = ...
anim.duration = ...
[view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"some key"];
// Then add the UIPanGestureRecognizer to that view.
```

Comment: And how can i do this? So, now i'm using UIView animation and I move the object frame, but with CABasicAnimation how can i do the same thing?

Comment: So the object is moving and when the user taps it, it should stop moving and follow his pan gesture? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, is that what i want! @iMasa